# For any finite group $H$, there's a composition series for $A_{\infty}\times H$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, infinite-groups

Denote $A_{\infty}=\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}A_{n}$. For any finite group $H$, the group $A_{\infty}\times H$ have a composition series.

I've shown that $A_{\infty}$ is simple, therefore it's composition series is $A_{\infty}\vartriangleright\left\{ \text{Id}\right\} $. I know that $H$ have some composition series because it's finite. I think the composition series for $A_{\infty}\times H$ would be something like:
$\left(A_{\infty}\times H_{0}\right)\vartriangleright\left(\left\{ Id\right\} \times H_{0}\right)\vartriangleright\left(\left\{ Id\right\} \times H_{1}\right)\vartriangleright\left(\left\{ Id\right\} \times H_{2}\right)\vartriangleright\dots\vartriangleright\left(\left\{ Id\right\} \times\left\{ e\right\} \right)$
but I'm not sure how to prove that $\left(A_{\infty}\times H_{0}\right)/\left(\left\{ Id\right\} \times H_{0}\right)$ is indeed simple.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\norm}{\trianglelefteq}$In general, if $G, H$ are groups, and $N \norm G$, $M \norm H$, then $N \times M \norm G \times H$, and
$$
\frac{G \times H}{N \times M}
\cong \frac{G}{N} \times \frac{H}{M}.
$$
This you see by checking that the map
\begin{align}
f :\ &G \times H \to \frac{G}{N} \times \frac{H}{M}\\
     &(g, h) \mapsto (g N, h M)
\end{align}
is a surjective homomorphism whose kernel is $N \times M$, and then applying the first isomorphism theorem.

In your case, then,
$$
\frac{A_{\infty}\times H_{0}}{ \left\{Id\right\} \times H_{0}} \cong A_{\infty}
$$
is simple.